# Apache hybris configuration to proxy pass HTTP and HTTP(S) yacceleratorstorefront (electronic store) URL to Hybris Server

Tags: apache, ssl, tomcat, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to access the yacceleratorstorefront/electronics/en/?site=electronics URL from apache web server to Hybris where the electronic store URL is configured. The electronic store URL is accessible and working from any of the server in environment if apache web server is BY PASSED

http://10.0.1.141:9001 is my Hybris server.

ERROR ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

HTTP Status 500 - Cannot find CMSSite associated with current URL ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

type Status report

message Cannot find CMSSite associated with current URL

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

Any suggestion or advice is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

-Regards, S@BS

------------------------------------------------httpd Code below----------------------------------------------------

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass / http://10.0.1.141:9001/ 
 ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.1.141:9001/

ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName localhost

#ProxyRequests Off
 #ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass / https://10.0.1.141:9002/yacceleratorstorefront/electronics/en/?site=electronics
 ProxyPassReverse / https://10.0.1.141:9002/yacceleratorstorefront/electronics/en/?site=electronics

SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/certs/mysite.com.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/certs/mysite.com.key

</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you are not setting the `?site=electronics` parameter at the http version of you proxy (it also seems to be missing in the proxypass setting for port 80).
I'm not an apache buff but maybe it works if you configure your proxy settings for port 80 in the same way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass / http://10.0.1.141:9001/?site=electronics
ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.1.141:9001/?site=electronics

ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Just some more info: Apart from the `site` parameter approach you can also use a host name approach.
Not sure if you have access to the hybris wiki, but here are some more details:
https://wiki.hybris.com/display/pmtelco/Using+Modulegen+to+Create+a+B2C+Telco+Setup#UsingModulegentoCreateaB2CTelcoSetup-AccessingtheStorefront
(its for Telco accelerator, but it works the same for any other storefront).
Not sure how that works together with apache, I assume you have to setup some sub domains or something.

Does it work if you try to access apache on https directly? (There it seems you have the correct url containing the site parameter).

Note: The site parameter is basically only needed for the first http request of a session. It is used to determine which storefront, i.e. BaseSite is supposed to be used. All subsequent requests (of the same session) shouldn't require the site parameter.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks much Sebastian. Let me try and I will come back to you with results.

Answer (score 0):

Your http config is fine. Your https config is wrong.

Do not put ?site=electronics or anything like that in your apache config.

The site detection works based on the URL. In the sample data you are using that is at least a regex looking for "electronics" in the hostname.

One single apache config will be able to support all sites. You do not need to specify the site. You do not need to specify /yacceleratorstorefront.

Simply edit your hosts file to include "10.0.1.141 electronics.rtfm"

Now access http://electronics.rtfm/

Comment: Hello @Stretch, thanks for your time and insights. Well, this is the complete URL "https://10.0.1.141:9002/yacceleratorstorefront/electronics/en/?site=electronics" to which a specific site on 10.0.1.141 server responds. The "/" would proxy the request to its home page on the same server 10.0.1.141, but the home page is not what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid adding the site in the URL by going in HMC: `WCMS > Websites`
Under the `Properties` tab, add a new URL pattern that will match your site.

Once it is done, URLs that match the site's pattern will automatically use that site.

Using URL patterns for each site will simplify the web server's configuration.